# Sudden increase of deletion rate for all of my iOS applications

Tags: app-store-connect, analytics, ios13

I have  a problem since last September 25 in all of my programs where the percentage of deletion recorded in itunes connect jumped from 35%  to 200% ؜ or more.
The percentage of crashes is stable as well as the active users.
I strongly expect that there is a relation between the deletion and the updating to iOS13, but I have not yet detected the accurate reason of the problem to solve it.
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Apple has announced yesterday in 2 November 2019 that there is a problem in the deletion calculation so the previous deletion records were incorrect, Apple has disabled the deletion recording and will enable it after correcting.

[image: App deletions data was reported incorrectly for iOS and tvOS as of August 2019. This data has been removed from the dashboard for reprocessing and will be re-enabled once reprocessing is done]